# Shift Geo Point with Pitagora's theorem

Tags: javascript, geometry

I have two geo point with WGS84 and a line that links these two points.
I need to split this line in two chunks shifting the middle point to build an half rhombus.

What I have:

- A coords (ex. 47.2270293988673, 4.06494140625);
- B coords;
- len of the shift;
- D coords;

What I need:

- C coords;

To calc D coords, im using:

```
calcMidPoint(position01, position02)
    {
        var lat1 = position01[1];
        var lon1 = position01[0];
        var lat2 = position02[1];
        var lon2 = position02[0];

        var dLon = this.toRad(lon2 - lon1);

        //convert to radians
        lat1 = this.toRad(lat1);
        lat2 = this.toRad(lat2);
        lon1 = this.toRad(lon1);

        var Bx = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);
        var By = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dLon);
        var lat3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(lat1) + Math.sin(lat2), Math.sqrt((Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) * (Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) + By * By));
        var lon3 = lon1 + Math.atan2(By, Math.cos(lat1) + Bx);
        return [ this.toDegrees(lat3), this.toDegrees(lon3) ];
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build perpendicular to DB.

At first, calculate bearing of DB (note in general case it differs from AB and BA bearings) useng bearing section at [this page](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

```
JavaScript:     (all angles     in radians)
var y = Math.sin(λ2-λ1) * Math.cos(φ2);
var x = Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2) -
        Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(φ2)*Math.cos(λ2-λ1);
var brng = Math.atan2(y, x);
```

Then add Pi/2 to this value `DCBrng = brng + Pi/2` and calculate desination point C using DCBrng and distance "len of the shift"

```
JavaScript:     (all angles     in radians)

var φ2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(d/R) +
                    Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );

var λ2 = λ1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(φ1),
                         Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2));

The longitude can be normalised to −180…+180 using (lon+540)%360-180
```